# Search column for string text with numbers then use =mid to extract 2 numbers

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to recording macros and being able to edit the recorded macro to a more generalized state so that the macro can be run on different spreadsheets. 
I am sorry if this has been answered before, I did search but as you can see from my title, I am having some difficulty explaining what I am trying to do.

[updated screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gV9Y4.png)

As you can see, I have mixed data in Column A, whereas I would like to have just the two numbers to the left of the "-".  I have used =MID(A9,17,2) to get the desired result which is 02, however, it is not guaranteed that the data will always be in A96 as these are exported summary reports of individual matters. I should also mention that the string data will always be the same length but not the same "name" SE2013000123.00002-1.

After the mid formula is run, I need to apply the formula to all cells which have the string in it.

I have recorded a macro but am at a loss as to what I need to take out and how to search based on a variable data search (is that the correct terminology?).

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test2()
'
' Test2 Macro
'

'
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("B96").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(RC[-1],17,2)"
Range("B97").Select
End Sub
Sub Value()
'
' Value Macro
'

'
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Might be my eyesight but that picture is so small I can't read it.

Comment: Please be more specific.  You have a column of data similar to "SE2013000123.00002-1".  You want to use the mid function to find a subset string within a particular cell.  Are you looking specifically for the 17th and 18th characters and are you searching for "02"?  You don't need to mess around with sheet formula functions.  VBA has it's own MID(string, start char, number of char's to get).  Assign it to a string variable - ie, myString = mid(range("B97",17,2) - which would equal "02" - then you can change to numeric or leave as string.

Comment: @JohnMuggins in my law firm we have matters starting with LA, SD or SE. In the string of text SE2013000123.00001-2, I really only need the two numbers to the left of the dash.  in this case the 01.  After I get this data I would copy and paste it back into column A so that I can concatenate columns A, C and D.  =CONCAT(A2,".",C2," ",D2). After that I plan to copy and paste as value to have just the data and no formula.  I'm not sure if this all makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

As text-that-looks-like a number,

```
with worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range(.cells(96, "B"), .cells(.rows.count, "A").end(xlup).offset(0, 1).Formula = "=MID(A96, FIND(CHAR(45), A96)-2, 2)"
end with
```

As a true number,

```
with worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range(.cells(96, "B"), .cells(.rows.count, "A").end(xlup).offset(0, 1).Formula = "=--MID(A96, FIND(CHAR(45), A96)-2, 2)"
end with
```